# I am getting a divide by 0, how can I make this query more robust?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, divide-by-zero

I believe the division below is what's causing the null, how do I use something like isNull, return 0?

The below query grabs the total net every day and attributes the value to a day of the week on Saturday, Sunday and week day. The idea is to get the average net based on a week day or Saturdays or Sundays.

But as this is still early in the month of August, there's not yet a count for Saturday or Sunday so dividing by 0 to get the average instead causes this error, how can I better handle this?

```
--@DespatchFrom = '08-01-2021'
--@DespatchFrom = '08-04-2021'

Select E_SAT.SATNet/E_SAT.SATCount As E_SAT,
E_SUN.SUNNet/E_SUN.SUNCount AS E_SUN,
E_WK.WKNet/E_WK.WKCount AS E_WK
from
(select DateDiff(ww, @DespatchFrom, @DespatchTo) as SATCount, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TranType = 'SRT' THEN (Net*-1) ELSE Net END) as SATNet
                from trans t
                where d t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) and t.despatchDateTime <= DateAdd(d,1,(@DespatchTo))
                and t.cancelleddocket = '0' and t.trantype <> 'DIV'
and DatePart("w",t.Despatchdatetime) = 7)
AS E_SAT,

(select DateDiff(ww, @DespatchFrom, @DespatchTo) as SUNCount, 
SUM(CASE WHEN TranType = 'SRT' THEN (Net*-1) ELSE Net END) as SUNNet
                from trans t
                where t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) and t.despatchDateTime <= DateAdd(d,1,(@DespatchTo))
                and t.cancelleddocket = '0' and t.trantype <> 'DIV'
and DatePart("w",t.Despatchdatetime) = 1)
AS E_SUN,

(select 
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @DespatchFrom, @DespatchTo) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @DespatchFrom, @DespatchTo) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @DespatchFrom) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @DespatchTo) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WKCount
  , SUM(CASE WHEN TranType = 'SRT' THEN (Net*-1) ELSE Net END) as WKNet
                from trans t
                where t.DespatchDateTime >= (@DespatchFrom) and t.despatchDateTime <= DateAdd(d,1,(@DespatchTo))
                and t.cancelleddocket = '0' and t.trantype <> 'DIV'
and ((DatePart("w",t.Despatchdatetime) > 1) AND (DatePart("w",t.Despatchdatetime) < 7)))
AS E_WK
```

Comment: What do you want to happen when the value is zero? Set the value to 1 (or something else) so that the division doesn't error or set the result of the whole calculation to some fixed value (or something completely different)?

Comment: @NickW it should be 0, weird thing is my report has been working for months and all of a sudden I get this divide by 0 error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result of the calculation to be zero then I'd use a CASE statement, something like:

```
CASE WHEN E_SAT.SATCount = 0 THEN 0 
ELSE E_SAT.SATNet/E_SAT.SATCount END As E_SAT
```